# Input String was not in a correct format

Tags: c#

Me esta saliendo la siguiente excepción, al retornar el dato y procesar la lectura del indicador

```
  private float ProcesarLecturaIP(string lectura)
    {
        //Lectura esperada
        //\n 1G         0.0kg \r
        //\n 1GM         0.0kg \r
        //\nZ1GM        0.0kg \r
        string lecturaEsperada = "\n 1G         0.0kg \r";

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lectura))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        //Estos valores son CONSTANTES
        //\n 1GM         0.0kg \r
        string cadenaInicio = "\n 1GM";

        int inicio = lectura.IndexOf(cadenaInicio);

        if (inicio > 100000)
        {
            //\nZ1GM        0.0kg \r
            cadenaInicio = "\n 1GM";
            inicio = lectura.IndexOf(cadenaInicio);

            if (inicio > 0)
            {
                //\n 1G         0.0kg \r
                cadenaInicio = "\n 1G";
                inicio = lectura.IndexOf(cadenaInicio);
            }
        }

        string cadenaFin = "kg \r";

        int fin = lectura.IndexOf(cadenaFin);

        inicio += cadenaInicio.Length;

        fin -= cadenaInicio.Length;
        string data = lectura.Substring(inicio, fin).Trim();
        return (float)Convert.ToDouble(data); 

        #endregion
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Data**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que tienes en `data` no es un numero que se pueda castear a `double`

Comment: Y antes del `return` ¿qué valor tiene la variable `data`?

Comment: Pero ya he intentado convertir con varios tipos y sale lo mismo con todos

Comment: Debes empezar por depurar que tienes en `data` en ese momento.

Comment: Al fallar, si pones el mouse sobre la variable `data` que valor observas?

Comment: Ya esta en la pregunta la img

Comment: pero veo un cero con un punto a la derecha, eso no es un numero valido, por eso falla. Te interesa que si viene ese dato se convierta en un cero? lo pregunto porque podrias convertir sin que falle

Comment: @LeandroTuttini esta haciendo mal el substring, por eso le da el error

Comment: sumale 1 a fin y se acabaron tus problemas...

Comment: @gbianchi en realidad seria concatenar, porque es un string, seria `data += "0"`, asi tendrias el valor "0.0", eso si es un double valido que se puede parsear

Comment: el data que tiene 0. sale de hacer un substring, esta mal el substring ;) @LeandroTuttini --> string data = lectura.Substring(inicio, fin).Trim();

Comment: @gbianchi ahh hacias referencia a sumarle uno a los valores de fin al aplicar el substring, pense que hacias referencia a la cadena despeus de parseada

Comment: Muchachos lo arregle de esta manera muchas gracias,      string data = lectura.Substring(inicio, fin).Substring(1).Trim();